# How to Implement Generic CSRF Tokens with JQuery AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, csrf

I am currently developing jquery code that sends data to the server via ajax that is then inserted into the database based on the request parameters.

However,  I am rather concerned that this could be abused by CSRF attacks which would make things rather insecure. I have tried to research this and only find answers for specific frameworks such as django and rails where I am only after a generic implementation for use with PHP.

I have read that you can use the JQuery.ajaxsend() function to implement the code so that a token is sent with EVERY AJAX request however I have no idea how this can be implemented as JavaScript obviously has no access to the PHP session variables. Would the use of cookies be secure enough?

Basically I need to be able to check the origin of the request to ensure that the request is genuine and not a forged request used to take advantage of the system.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, do know that `$.ajax` seems to send the cookies, including the PHP session cookie, with its request.  Using that feature changes your attack from CSRF to session hijacking, but it's a start.  Next, run your service over SSL if you can to avoid the session hijacking.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this as well, but for vanilla PHP, this seems to work.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: This assumes that AJAX requests are authenticated by something in the session.

Comment: Well the user will need to be logged in, in order for them to have access. So there will be checks with the PHP session for authentication.

Comment: Also there doesn't seem to be any session cookie info being sent with $.ajax.

Comment: @MichaelMior Yes, I took the mention of "JavaScript obviously has no access to the PHP session variables" to mean that there is a PHP session that would be useful in validating the request.

Comment: @DanielWest Hrm...  I wrote something just last night that relied on that being the case, and it worked in Chrome at least with the method being `POST`.  Which browser?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah the user will need to be logged in so the script that the AJAX is being sent to will carry out the authentication checks. Doesn't AJAX have a rule against cross domain requests? If so is the token rather worthless?

Comment: @Andrew I'm currently using Chrome, PHP 5.3.8.1 and JQuery 1.7.1

Comment: @DanielWest The request can still be forged elsewhere; it's just the browser enforcing any cross-domain restrictions.  Plus, at least in my implementation, the token also tells me the user's authorization, not just authentication, which I can check on the server side.

Comment: @Andrew Hmmm yeah the origin policy of the browser, wasn't sure if it was going to be enough. Its just frustrating that JavaScript is so separate from the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's done in Django, but there's nothing that's framework specific (besides setting the CSRF token in the cookie as 'csrftoken'): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: So i'm guessing the token can be generated and added into the cookie on login by using PHP? As there is no function for generating the token in their example code.

Comment: Django uses middleware to add the CSRF token to the cookie on every page view (if it's not already there). Said middleware also checks every form post to validate that the CSRF token is there & correct (either in the POST params or in the X-CSRFToken header).